# How to log the time for each info message using log4j?

Tags: jar, console, log4j

I am new to log4j. I cloned a project from GitHub. Then, with maven I produced the jar file to run it through mac terminal.

```
mvn clean package
```

The output of the jar file is in this format:

```
[main] INFO cs.cuf.dm.org.someClassName - Result retrieved 
[main] INFO cs.cuf.dm.org.someClassName - Running Done
```

I want the results in this format:

```
2008-12-25 13:14:00 [main] INFO cs.cuf.dm.org.someClassName - Result retrieved 
2008-12-25 13:15:00 [main] INFO cs.cuf.dm.org.someClassName - Running Done
```

The cloned project contains many `log4j.properties` and `log4j2.xml` files, and here is the files setting:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=info
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm} [%t] %l - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.File=log/morphrdb.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=debug
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test"
status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="log4j.test.Log4jTest" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="Jena" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I tried to modify all the `log4j.properties` and `log4j2.xml` files, to make the PatternLayout follow this format:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n
```

However, nothing changed in the output on the console.
I recompiled and reproduced the jar file again using maven, but nothing change on the console.

What am I missing? Are there any steps that should I follow to reflect the changes in the `log4j.properties` and `log4j2.xml` files to the jar file?

Comment: Which project did you clone?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz This one https://github.com/oeg-upm/morph-rdb

Comment: That project seems to be using Log4j 1.x (i.e. `log4j.properties`), although the project structure is quite chaotic. You can use `-Dlog4j.configuration` to provide a config file.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz how can I use `-Dlog4j.configuration` ?

Comment: Set the `log4j.configuration` property to the path of the configuration file (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure), e.g. `-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/lala/log4j.properties`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz sorry for keep asking, but I am new to log4j. I set up the path using this command on mac terminal  `export TOMCAT_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=/src/test/log4j.properties"`, but also nothing changed the output is without date and time. As well, I cannot find the file `log/morphrdb.log`  that is defined in  `log4j.properties`